# mongoose return an object from an array based on condition

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, nosql

I want to get a specific object from an array in a record from MongoDB. I want to get the entire collection so I cannot apply my condition in find but inside the record, I have an array I want to return an object from that array based on a condition.

```
 await model
  .find({})
  .select("translations")
  .then((data: any) => {
    return res.status(200).json({
      data
    });
  });
```

Now here translations has many objects

```
[
 {id:'', name: 'EN'},
 {id:'', name: 'AR'}, 
 {id:'', name: 'FR'}
]
```

How can I only return the translation which has the name 'EN'

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    '$project': {
      'translation': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$translation', 
          'as': 't', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$t.name', 'EN'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]   
)
```